# Как сделать бургер-меню

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть обычное меню и из него мне нужно сделать бургер меню как на этом сайте (https://www.saxoprint.co.uk/), но когда я начинаю его делать сталкиваюсь например с тем, что мое меню не располагается по вертикали. Буду супер благодарна если сможете на основе моего меню сделать хоть немного рабочий бургер-меню. Спасибо)

```css
/* Menu
    ==========================*/

.menu {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #BDBDBD;
  /* text-align: center; */
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(26, 63, 119, 0.5);
}

.topmenu {
  padding: 0 51px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .2s linear;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.active {
  /* font-weight: bold; */
}

.topmenu>li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.topmenu>li>a {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

.a {
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

.topmenu>li:hover>a {
  color: #184fa3;
}

.active:after,
.submenu-link:after {
  color: inherit;
}

.topmenu>li:hover {
  color: #184fa3;
}

.submenu li a:hover {
  color: #DA1111;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #184fa3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px rgba(1, 102, 174, 0.22);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.submenu li {
  position: relative;
}

.submenu a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.submenu .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

nav li:hover>.submenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<!-- Menu-->
<nav class="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu-burger__header">
    <span></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="topmenu">
      <li><a href="" class="a">рекламная продукция</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="">Визитки</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Листовки</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Многостраничные изделия</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Плакаты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Упаковка</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Конверты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Папки</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Календари</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Пакеты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Календарные сетки</a></li>
          <li><a href="">СТР формы</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Изделия нестандартных размеров</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="" class="a">картонная упаковка</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="a">флексо печать</a></li>
      <!-- <li><a href="" class="a">Производственные мощности</a></li> -->
      <li><a href="" class="a">контакты</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="a">о нас</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav
```

Answer (score 2):

Переписал стили, вёрстка не затронута.
Используется немного JS.

```js
let burger = document.querySelector('.menu-burger__header'),
    menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

burger.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  menu.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}

.menu.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.menu .container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

/* burger */

.menu .menu-burger__header {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% + 10px);
  top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* burger | open */

.menu .menu-burger__header::before,
.menu .menu-burger__header > span,
.menu .menu-burger__header::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.menu .menu-burger__header::before {
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  transform-origin:
  transition-property: top, transform;
}

.menu .menu-burger__header > span {
  top: 50%;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.menu .menu-burger__header::after {
  top: calc(50% + 8px);
  transition-property: top, transform;
}

/* burger active | close */

.menu.active .menu-burger__header::before {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu.active .menu-burger__header > span {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu.active .menu-burger__header::after {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

/* menu list */

.menu .topmenu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu .topmenu a {
  display: block;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu .topmenu > li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.menu .topmenu > li > a {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* submenu list */

.menu .topmenu .submenu {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-top: .5em;
}

.menu .topmenu .submenu > li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.menu .topmenu .submenu li:hover {
  color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<!-- Menu-->
<nav class="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu-burger__header">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="topmenu">
      <li>
        <a href="" class="a">рекламная продукция</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="">Визитки</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Листовки</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Многостраничные изделия</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Плакаты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Упаковка</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Конверты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Папки</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Календари</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Пакеты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Календарные сетки</a></li>
          <li><a href="">СТР формы</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Изделия нестандартных размеров</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="" class="a">картонная упаковка</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="a">флексо печать</a></li>
      <!-- <li><a href="" class="a">Производственные мощности</a></li> -->
      <li><a href="" class="a">контакты</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="a">о нас</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```